# Name and address orientation

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm working on a `moderncv` document and my cv style is:

```
\moderncvstyle{banking}.
```

In this style format, name, address and mobile numbers are middle aligned. But I want the `name` to be left aligned and address and contact numbers to right aligned without using `moderncvstyle{casual}`.

Here is how my cv looks like right now (`banking` style):

[image]

I want it to be aligned like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the header you wants can be rebuild by using the header of style `classic` (and not `casual` as you mentioned).

In this case simple do not add an photo to your cv (or comment the existing one) and call the header before begining the document in style `banking` with

```
\moderncvhead{1} % Head of classic style    % <=========================
```

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a} % <===============================
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt} 

\moderncvhead{1} % Head of classic style    % <=========================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the default title/header under `banking` in [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv):

[image]

Copy the content from [`makecvheadi.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadi.sty) into your preamble - used under the [`casual` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylecasual.sty) to set the header (surrounded by a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)) and remove the `\photo` specification:

[image]

```
\makeatletter
% lengths
\@initializelength{\quotewidth}
% optional makecvheadname width to force a certain width (if set/remains to 0pt, the width is calculated automatically)
\@initializelength{\makecvheadnamewidth}
\renewcommand*{\recomputecvheadlengths}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.65\textwidth}}

% commands
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \llap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\fi%
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sadly I don't have enough reputation points to give an upvote. Sorry for that.